# Set maximum scale of ViewBox

Tags: wpf

Is it somehow possible to set a maximum scale of the content in a ViewBox? If I have this code for instance, I want to ensure that the text is not scaled more than 200%

```
<Grid>
    <Viewbox>
        <TextBox Text="Hello world" />
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight` on `ViewBox`:

```
<Grid>
    <Viewbox x:Name="MyViewBox">
        <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Text="Hello world" />
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

and in code behind:

```
MyViewBox.MaxWidth = MyTextBox.ActualWidth * 2d;
MyViewBox.MaxHeight = MyTextBox.ActualHeight * 2d;
```

Or maybe better solution with converter:

```
public class ViewBoxMaxWidthOrHeightConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double textBoxWidthOrHeight = (double) value;
        return textBoxWidthOrHeight*2d;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and XAML:

```
<local:ViewBoxMaxWidthOrHeightConverter x:Key="ViewBoxMaxWidthOrHeightConverter"/>
                <Grid>
                    <Viewbox x:Name="MyViewBox" 
                             MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBox, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource ViewBoxMaxWidthOrHeightConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
                             MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBox, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource ViewBoxMaxWidthOrHeightConverter}, Mode=OneWay}">
                        <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Text="Hello world" />
                    </Viewbox>
                </Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you :-). That was an elegant and easy solution.

Answer (score 5):

For future readers, I've written an even more elegant approach based on user2250152's answer that uses an attached property:

```
public static class ViewboxExtensions
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxZoomFactorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MaxZoomFactor", typeof(double), typeof(ViewboxExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(1.0, OnMaxZoomFactorChanged));

    private static void OnMaxZoomFactorChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var viewbox = d as Viewbox;
        if (viewbox == null)
            return;
        viewbox.Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private static void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var viewbox = sender as Viewbox;
        var child = viewbox?.Child as FrameworkElement;
        if (child == null)
            return;

        child.SizeChanged += (o, args) => CalculateMaxSize(viewbox);
        CalculateMaxSize(viewbox);
    }

    private static void CalculateMaxSize(Viewbox viewbox)
    {
        var child = viewbox.Child as FrameworkElement;
        if (child == null)
            return;
        viewbox.MaxWidth = child.ActualWidth * GetMaxZoomFactor(viewbox);
        viewbox.MaxHeight = child.ActualHeight * GetMaxZoomFactor(viewbox);
    }

    public static void SetMaxZoomFactor(DependencyObject d, double value)
    {
        d.SetValue(MaxZoomFactorProperty, value);
    }

    public static double GetMaxZoomFactor(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (double)d.GetValue(MaxZoomFactorProperty);
    }
}
```

The attached property can be added to a viewbox like this:

```
<Viewbox extensions:ViewboxExtensions.MaxZoomFactor="2.0">...</Viewbox>
```

Comment: I was unable to get this to work. There's an erroneous ? in the OnLoaded method, and when I add the attached property, I get the error "'ViewboxExtensions' type must derive from DependencyObject." But if I add that inheritance I get "Static class 'ViewboxExtensions' cannot derive from type 'DependencyObject'. Static classes must derive from object." I don't know WPF well enough to get past this.

Comment: Oh, I think I wrote this snippet for UWP, so it's possible that it doesn't work with WPF. Didn't look at the tag of the original question... You might be able to convert this to WPF if you find out how attached properties behave differently in UWP and WPF. Unfortunately I'm on holiday and don't have machine with me that allows Windows development. The ? is correct usage in C# 6 and is called a null-conditional operator.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the reply! I'm not well versed enough in this framework to figure out the differences, but it's not critical.

Comment: Then it's probably best to use the way proposed in the other answer. This is what my attached property is based on.

Comment: lol. First line, replace Register with RegisterAttached :D Works perfect.